# Suitescript email limitations

Tags: javascript, email, netsuite, suitescript

I am having an issue with sending emails from SuiteSript 1.0 scheduled scripts.

I have a scheduled script which makes use of a saved search. The script runs every hour and sends an email for each result in the saved search.

I find that some of the search results are often not emailed to the recipient. This especially happens when there are many results from the saved search. There does not seem to be a specific limit on the amount of emails that can be sent.
I say this because I have tried to send 8 emails, where only 5 were successfully sent. I have also tried to send 37 email, where 12 emails were successfully sent.

The emails that do get sent successfully are also not sequential - i.e. when sending 8 emails, the 2nd and 5th result may not be emailed as expected.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Adding some code for clarification:

```
    if (curRec.getFieldValue('location')  === '6' ||curRec.getFieldValue('location') === '14' && curRec.getFieldValue('department') === '3' && curRec.getFieldValue('custbody_sales_order_type') == '10')
       {
         nlapiSendEmail(fromId, 'Test@server.com', sbj, msg, null, null, null, newFileObj);
         nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Email Notification', 'Order ' + curRec.getFieldValue('id') + ' should now be sent');
       }
```

The above log message is received for each expected email, but all emails do not arrive at the recipient address.

Comment: Is there any up-to-date documentation of Netsuite Limitations ?

Comment: You can search for "limitations" or specific limitations, such as "email limitations" on the NetSuite Help Center. You need a login to access this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answer from M. Pope is correct and seemed to make a difference, it turns out that the emailing functionality is simply very unreliable. All emails do not reach their destination.

I resolved this by dropping this functionality altogether and making use of NetSuite's SFTP functionality to pass orders to my own software systems.

A resource for getting started with this: [NetSuite SFTP with SuiteScript 2.0](http://netsuite.folio3.com/blog/netsuite-sftp-module/)

Answer (score 2):

have you set the last parameter to true?

```
nlapiSendEmail(sender, recipients , subject, body, ccs, bccs, associated_record, attachment, not_a_bulk_email);
```

Setting `not_a_bulk_email` to true is important.  I ran into an issue a while ago because I didn't know what the parameter did.  If not set, it sends the email as bulk email, which causes the email to be sent with less priority (sometimes hours later) and to not notify on failures.

On the other hand, if set to true, it will send immediately.  However, this  limits the amount of recipients + ccs + bccs to 10.

Let me know if that works out to you.

Also, if you could post a code sample, that'd be awesome too.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have added this parameter and will post feedback later on how this worked. My code is very simple - I check a few conditions and then send an email with attached file, I have added this to my post above.. The above code does not include your suggested change - I did add this to my solution though.

Comment: Hey I changed my answer a little bit.  Setting not_a_bulk_email to true DOES limit it to 10 email addresses.  Sorry about that.  Typo!

Comment: I still have the same problem. 35 emails were sent from my script, but only 20 made it to the recipient address. After each loop and when the nlapiSendEmail method has been called, I log the execution of sending that email. 35 of these logs were produced, so the nlapiSendEmail  method must have been called each time. I added this to my code above.

Comment: Hey, just looking at the code you posted, I'm not seeing the last paramater set (did you leave it out of the example)?  You'd want:   `nlapiSendEmail(fromId, 'Test@server.com', sbj, msg, null, null, null, newFileObj, true);`  Also, note if you do this, the governance will be 20 units, and not 10.

Comment: This means you'd be limited on the number of times you can call it (35 times would be 700 of the 1000 units possible in a User Event script).